# How to connect a project with multiple azure functions to Azure deployment center using github?

Tags: c#, azure, github, azure-functions

I have a project that contains two c# azure functions. I'm trying to deploy them to Azure Function App using github. When I attach my repository in the Azure deployment center portal I get the following error:

```
Unable to determine which project file to build. C:\home\site\repository\{ResumeTriggerPath}, C:\home\site\repository\{BlobTriggerPath}
```

Ideally, I would like it to add both functions. My current directory structure is:

|- host.json
|- HttpTriggerFunction/
|- BlobTriggerFunction/
|- Shared/

Shared is a folder that has shared files between the two functions. I don't have any special configurations in the host.json file. Is there anything I can add that specifies to build both? Is there documentation on how I can use multiple functions in the same project? The expected outcome is that both functions are added to the "Functions" section is the Azure Function App.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. create the Azure function in Azure portal
2. download publish profile of the function from Azure (the option 'Get publish profile' from the function Overview)
3. publish the project from Visual Studio and select to import the profile created in the previous step when picking a publish target

[image]

Comment: I want to be able to publish when I make changes to the github repository. I don't believe I'll be able to based on how it's structured anyways since there's a shared folder so I may just end up deleting one of the functions.